# Transofrm sql query to wordpress query with new wp_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress

I am trying to convert an sql query to an wordpress query but fail to understand how is it done?

Query that I try to convert to `new wp_query`

```
$query = "  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct wp_posts.ID
            FROM   wp_posts
                   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
                           ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id )
                   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
                           ON ( wp_posts.id = mt1.post_id )
            WHERE  1 = 1
                   AND wp_posts.id NOT IN ( 0 )
                   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'topic'
                   AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                          OR wp_posts.post_status = 'closed'
                          OR wp_posts.post_status = 'reported' )
                   AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_bbp_last_active_time')
            GROUP  BY wp_posts.id
            ORDER  BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC
            LIMIT  0, 10 
        ";
$topics = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
```

so I can use

```
while($topics->have_posts()) : $topics->the_post(); ?>
```

smth like

```
$args = array(); // how do I convert to this.
$topics = new WP_query($args);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$wpq = new WP_Query();
$wpq->parse_query($query);
$posts = $wpq->get_posts();
```

or to use the standard WP_Query functions:

```
$wpq = new WP_Query($query);
```

Comment: nothing appearing and tested on sql and should appear

Comment: added like this: `$topics = new WP_Query();
          $topics->parse_query($query);` and after that the while abd doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the answer. I should have noted that you need to get the posts of you do that. Re-reading your question, I think that you probably want the second format.

Comment: Did not knew that new qp query can process sql.

Comment: -1 I accidentally voted this up cause it looked like it was working. But it turns out it doesn't. Initializing the WP_Query like this will return all post types based on default settings, but seems like it will not take into account the passed SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried bobdye's solution, but it turns out it's not working. The only way, as far as I know to set up a loop where you can go and use the `the_title()`, `$post->ID` and so on, is to work like this:

```
global $post;

$sql_results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql_query, OBJECT);

if ($sql_results) {
    foreach ($sql_results as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post);

      // You're in the loop now. You can access all the $post objects
      // and functions like in any other wp loop.
      // example: the_title();

    }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

A problem with this is pagination. But I believe this answer solves it neatly:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21626/pagination-with-custom-sql-query#28717